# JavaScript for Tailwind Navbar Burger Menu

Tags: javascript, navbar, tailwind-css

I am looking at the basic tailwind **navbar** example https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/navigation/navbars with a **burger menu**.

When I use the sample `HTML` code together with the tailwind `css` file, it all looks great. But the burger menu button does not work. The link above states `REQUIRES JS`, but I am unable to find any `js` file with the required code snippet.

I assume I need some java script that makes use of `aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false"` and then toggles the burger button icons between `<svg class="block ...">` and `<svg class="hidden ...">`. Can anyone direct me to where tailwind's JS is documented?

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
let menu=document.getElementById('menu')
let hamburgerBTN=document.getElementById('hamburger')
hamburgerBTN.addEventListener('click',()=>{
menu.classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).